# how to set in one logic to render the component from given code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function Representation() {

const [isPieClick, setIsPieClick] = useState(false);
const [isBarClick, setIsBarClick] = useState(false);

const pieClick = () => {
    setIsPieClick(true);
  };

  const barClick = () => {
    setIsBarClick(true);
  };

return(

  <div>
     <button className="btn1" type="button" onClick={pieClick}>
        Pie Chart
     </button>
     <button className="btn1" type="button" onClick={barClick}>
        Bar Chart
     </button>
     <div>
        {isPieClick && <PieChartComponent data={maxData} />}
        {isBarClick && <BarChartComponent data={maxData} />}
     </div>
   </div>

 )
}
```

from the above code snippet the following code snippet work to render both chart component in the page.

```
<div>
   {isPieClick && <PieChartComponent data={maxData} />}
   {isBarClick && <BarChartComponent data={maxData} />}
</div>
```

**My problem** is I want to set the logic into one logic which should work for both button to render the component individually.

Comment: You can do it, but why? This snippet is readable enough, do you mean you want to have one function to control both click states? So why not having a single state instead?

Comment: basically i want
if i click Pie chart then pie chart should be rendered.
and again i click Bar chart then the bar chart should be rendered and pie chart should be not seen. Thus if i click pie chart the piechart  component should be rendered and bar chart component should not be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Edit I misunderstood the question, here's an example of how you could toggle the bar and pie chart:

```
export default function Representation() {

const [isPieClick, setIsPieClick] = useState(false);
const [isBarClick, setIsBarClick] = useState(false);

const pieClick = () => {
    setIsPieClick(true);
    setIsBarClick(false);
  };

  const barClick = () => {
    setIsBarClick(true);
    setIsPieClick(false);
  };

return(

  <div>
     <button className="btn1" type="button" onClick={pieClick}>
        Pie Chart
     </button>
     <button className="btn1" type="button" onClick={barClick}>
        Bar Chart
     </button>
     <div>
        {isPieClick && <PieChartComponent data={maxData} />}
        {isBarClick && <BarChartComponent data={maxData} />}
     </div>
   </div>

 )
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
i worked in a function to toggle the bar and pie chart where setState not work as i want.
But you set it simply and that is worked.

Comment: You're welcome. So, is setState still not working? How do you want it to work? Edit - oh I see, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```js
const PIE = "PIE";
const BAR = "BAR";

export default function Representation() {
  const [chartType, setChartType] = useState(PIE);

  const setPieChart = () => setChartType(PIE);
  const setBarChart = () => setChartType(BAR);

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="btn1" type="button" onClick={setPieChart}>
        Pie Chart
      </button>
      <button className="btn1" type="button" onClick={setBarChart}>
        Bar Chart
      </button>
      <div>
        {chartType === PIE ? (
          <PieChartComponent data={maxData} />
        ) : (
          <BarChartComponent data={maxData} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

UI nit: You might want to put this logic in a radio button group, dropdown or a switch if there are only two chart types.